# Find a sine function for this graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I'm trying to find the equation for this graph, and my answer was:

Amplitude: $2$
Period: $1$ because $\pi/2 + 3\pi/2 = 2\pi$
Phase Shift: $-\pi/2$
Vertical shift: $-2$

So my answer is:
$$2\sin(x + \pi/2) - 2$$
The problem is that when I enter this equation in [Desmos Graphing Calcultor](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xjx15igpsf) to make sure that my answer is right, I get similar graph but not the same one in my booklet

So what's wrong with my equation?

[image: Find a sine and cosine function for the graph below]

Comment: this graph is $2\sin(\frac{1}{2}(x-\pi /2))-2$

Comment: So your period and phase shift is wrong.

Comment: its period is $4\pi$ is easy to observe

Answer (score 1):

Booklet plot is a plot of $ 2 (\sin(x /2 - \pi/4) - 1),\,  -2 \pi <x <2 \pi. $